# ImportError while importing test module, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

This is the error raised:

```
test_server.py:None (test_server.py)
ImportError while importing test module '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-  22.04\home\jasmi\sprint9_unittest\new\test\17-01-2024TM\TestManager\tests\dataserver\test_mainserver.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
```

[image: project structure]

When I tried unittest test on mainserver.py, I got an import error. I think imported properly, so I don't why it comes `your text`